# How do I make a partially-free open-core product that permits custom plugins?

Tags: gpl, closed-source, terminology, plugins, combined-work

I have a native application I would like to release under a copyleft license. The application embeds a Lua interpreter and exposes an application-specific interface to Lua code. I would like to release the application under a copyleft license and the Lua code under a proprietary license.

According to the GNU FAQ I can't use the GPL as the [native application and Lua code have intimate communication and therefore constitute a single combined work](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLAndPlugins). The LGPL might work as it defines a separation between the GPL and proprietary component.

My question is: is the terminology defined in "0. Additional Definitions" of the LGPLv3 literal or abstract? i.e. Given the definitions of "Application" and "Library" can I assign them to the components based on their role? Or are the terms literal i.e. "Application" literally means executable program and "Library" literally means linkable library?

Comment: Lua appears to be under MIT License, which is compatible with GPL. Why do you think your application cannot be published under the GPL license?

Comment: I rather agree with Martin.  This question seems to be conflating what you **want** to do, and what you think you **have** to do.  If you tell us what you're doing (what pre-existing code are you using, from where, under what licence, and what are you adding to it) and what you want to do (do you want the resulting binary to be redistributable?  under what terms?) we'll try to take care of the obligations bit.

Comment: There is the Lua interpreter and then there are the Lua scripts that run against it. The former is embedded in the native application, the latter are separate/loose files that are loaded by the interpreter and depend upon an API exposed by the native application. I want to release the native app under a copyleft license and Lua scripts under a proprietary license. I'm asking about the LGPL because according to the GNU FAQ the GPL requires programs with intimate communication, which the native app and Lua scripts appear to have, to both be GPL which is not what I want.

Comment: The way I see it is that the license of the Lua interpreter and the licenses of the Lua scripts are independent (i.e. their licenses don't have implications for each other). I see similarities with JS Interpreters and JS code.

Comment: [GNU explicitly OK's this usage](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#IfInterpreterIsGPL) however, they also state "...when the interpreter is extended to provide 'bindings' to other facilities...the interpreted program is effectively linked to the facilities it uses through these bindings. So if these facilities are released under the GPL, the interpreted program that uses them must be released in a GPL-compatible way." In my case, the application not only embeds a Lua interpreter but also exposes a Lua API to app-specific data structures.

Comment: I concur with your analysis, but have you not thus answered your own question?  Because you have extended a GPL interpreter to expose the internals to intepreted code, your scripts (interpreter input) are now copyright derivatives of the interpreter, and so must be released, if at all, under the GPL.  At least that's how the FSF sees it, and I wouldn't bet against that interpretation.

Comment: I understand I can't use the GPL which is why I'm asking about the LGPL. The LGPL allows copyleft code to interface with proprietary code. My issue is the LGPL license terminology specifically describes the copyleft component as a "Library" and the other (proprietary) component as an "Application" which is the reverse of my use case. My question is: given the LGPL definitions of "Application" and "Library" (see section "0. Additional Definitions" of the LGPL) can I assign the terms to the components based on the license definitions or will I risk legal issues with this interpretation?

Comment: We're starting to go round in circles, which is rather characteristic of [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Can I call your attention to the questions asked in my first comment, above?

Comment: "what pre-existing code are you using, from where, under what licence": My company is the sole copyright owner of the executable and 1st party Lua code and they're not public yet. "do you want the resulting binary to be redistributable? under what terms?" We want the executable under a copyleft license and 1st and 3rd party Lua plugins under a proprietary license. "I concur with your analysis, but have you not thus answered your own question?": no because my question is about whether terminology in the LGPL can be assigned to the components based which license definitions they conform to.

Comment: Saying "a proprietary licence" isn't explicit enough.  Is this a proprietary licence that permits redistribution?  Verbatim only, or derivative works, or what?

Comment: Our plugin will be distributed in binary format, but we will grant paying clients access to its source. We want clients to be able to license their own plugins under their own terms. We'd like to release the application under a copyleft license that's lenient enough to not affect how clients license their plugins.

Comment: Ah, now we start to get to the meat of the problem: your desire to let clients create their own plugins.  Do you also desire that clients should be able to *distribute* these plugins, and if so do you care about the terms under which they do it, or should they be solely for internal use?  Also, you write about "*your plugin*"; do you mean "your executable" (made from your native application plus your lua code) or is that, too, plugging into something not previously disclosed?

Comment: Sorry, one more question: given the source of the application, and a copy of the running binary, would it be possible for clients to write plugins, or is sight of your Lua scripts also necessary?

Comment: "Do you also desire that clients should be able to distribute these plugins..." Clients should be able to license and distribute plugins completely under their own terms. "you write about 'your plugin'..." We have our own 1st party Lua plugins we would like to distribute under our own terms. There is only one executable. "given the source of the application, and a copy of the running binary, would it be possible for clients to write plugins...": yes - using the docs and source as reference. We also have starter plugins and samples under a public domain license to further help them.

Comment: Hmm, I was under the impression the MIT license is more lax and permissive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to release your application code under LGPL, but not alongside the binary.  When a paying customer buys the executable, convey the whole thing (binary, application source, your Lua scripts) to them under the proprietary licence that you intend should cover your Lua scripts.  However, also tell them that documentation and full application code, under LGPL, can be found at such-and-such a git repository, along with your "*starter plugins and samples under a public domain licence*".

This sidesteps the whole issue of (L)GPL expectations associated with the receipt of the binary, while making it clear that the LGPL codebase doesn't contain your Lua scripts.

On the offchance that a customer wants to sell or otherwise distribute their plugin, which you want them to be free to do, the LGPL as I read it will permit this - but you can add an explicit "plugin exemption" if you want to make it as clear as possible.

And as ever, IANAL/IANYL, so if you're going to bet a business on this, take professional legal advice.

Comment: I appreciate both the answer you and @ruben2020 gave. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be a common situation so it will ultimately be a lawyer question. While I like their answer too (for all I know a GPL exception will be what the lawyer suggests) I'm accepting yours because you engaged with me for many many many days. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to release your native application (including the MIT-licensed Lua interpreter) under the GPLv2 or GPLv3 with the [Classpath exception](https://www.gnu.org/software/classpath/license.html) (quoted below). It is also used in a similar way to your use case, by [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/legal/gplv2+ce.html) for running Java applications on top of the OpenJDK JVM.

The Lua apps can be proprietary, and it doesn't matter if they have "intimate communication" with the native application. There is also no requirement to provide the recipient with a way to relink the "independent modules" to the GPL-ed software, after modifying the latter.

> Linking this library statically or dynamically with other modules is
> making a combined work based on this library. Thus, the terms and
> conditions of the GNU General Public License cover the whole
> combination.
>
> As a special exception, the copyright holders of this library give you
> permission to link this library with independent modules to produce an
> executable, regardless of the license terms of these independent
> modules, and to copy and distribute the resulting executable under
> terms of your choice, provided that you also meet, for each linked
> independent module, the terms and conditions of the license of that
> module. An independent module is a module which is not derived from or
> based on this library. If you modify this library, you may extend this
> exception to your version of the library, but you are not obligated to
> do so. If you do not wish to do so, delete this exception statement
> from your version.

As for your second question with respect to "Application" and "Library" in the LGPL, I would say "Library" refers to the LGPL-licensed library and all its dependencies, while "Application" refers to any software, possibly an executable or even another library, that makes use of the LGPL-licensed library. The "Application" programmatically depends on the "Library", but the "Library" must not depend on the "Application". The "Application" must not be derived from the "Library", but merely using it.

IANAL.